# Try to read csv file from python programming

Tags: python, csv

I have kept csv file in D directory and trying to read that csv file using python programming.
This is my code in python:

```
import csv

try:
     path = "D:\\abc.csv"
     with open("path", "rb") as csvfile:
         readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
         for row in readCSV:
             print (row)    
except Exception, e:
    raise e
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
The current working directory is F:\
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\directory.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise e
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the double quotes around `path`. "path" is a string and in-order to get the value of `path` variable , you need to put the variable as it is, so that it got expanded.

```
with open(path, "rb") as csvfile:
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes around path. Edit it to this:

```
with open(path, "rb") as csvfile:
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
with open("path", "rb") as csvfile:
```

should be

```
with open(path, "rb") as csvfile:
```

As any text in "" or '' in python would be consider as string type instead of variable.

Comment: I have removed the double quotes around the path. Now i am getting following error:                                                                                                               The current working directory is F:\
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:\directory.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise e
     AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'

Comment: I think you have named the python script as csv.py Check out this link Please avoid naming .py script with common library names such as csv,os,etc as python will think you are import the .py instead of the library